# How to place text in view at locations specified by databinding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, uwp

The functionality I'm looking for is tappable labels where the both the text and locations are databound, and the locations are relative to the image that is also being displayed.

I've tried both `AbsoluteLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, but the labels don't seem to be able to escape the confines of the `CollectionView`; i.e the labels keep iterating down or across the page based on the label's size. I don't care if labels overlap each other. In fact if the label's font is large enough and the databound locations are close enough, then overlapping labels is a certainty and the tap event could logically happen to whatever label is on top at that pixel location. That is fine with me.

For example, I have an image that is 640x480 pixels in size that I want to display. The label' text and locations that I want placed over them need to be databound. Here is the sample `MockData`.

```
        public MockDataStore()
        {
            items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "A"  , Description="My A"  , X= 85, Y=130 },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "B"  , Description="My B"  , X=140, Y=150 },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "C"  , Description="My C"  , X=190, Y=165 },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "D"  , Description="My D"  , X=240, Y=175 },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "E"  , Description="My E"  , X=290, Y=180 },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "F"  , Description="My F"  , X=335, Y=185 }
            };
        }
```

And here is the XAML I'm trying.

```
    <Grid x:Name="grid" 
          x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel">
        <!--<Image Source="bg.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" x:Name="bg"/>-->
        <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" 
                        Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" 
                        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RelativeLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Constant={Binding X}}"
                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant={Binding Y}}"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                    FontSize="16" />
                            <RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </Grid>
```

What is happening is that the relative locations of the labels are being placed in incremented location down the page. I'm not married to using `CollectionView` as long as I can still get `ItemTapped`.

I've also tried using `BindableLayout` with no success, though I'm not sure I understand how to use that class correctly, and moreover the data source is all text and locations.

What I want to accomplish is similar to how a GPS app displays a map and overlays tappable points of interest that are loaded from data and relative to the coordinates within the map.

Is what I want to accomplish even possible using Xamarin's XAML?

EDIT: I have discovered that `RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0, Constant=0}" TranslationX="{Binding X}"` will place the labels at the correct X location. However, this idea doesn't work with the Y location. `CollectionView` keeps incrementing the Y location down the page. I wish `CollectionView` could be set to not do any positioning of controls and just allow me to set the label's x/y position via binding.

Comment: I don't think you could bind X for XConstraint with above, it throw exception `No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Constant", or mismatching type between value and property` could you explain how bind this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will place the labels at the correct X location. However, this idea doesn't work with the Y location.

The problem is you display the label in **each** CollectionView item, But they have different RelativeLayout parent. And it has enough width for setting Y value, but not for X value.

For this scenario, we suggest you compose items with `BindableLayout`

**For example**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <local:ItemsViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<RelativeLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <Label
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                FontSize="16"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding X}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding Y}"
                Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
public class ItemsViewModel
{
    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        MockDataStore();
    }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public void MockDataStore()
    {
        items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "A"  , Description="My A"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(85),Y= Constraint.Constant(130)},
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "B"  , Description="My B"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(140),Y= Constraint.Constant(150)},
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "C"  , Description="My C"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(190),Y= Constraint.Constant(165)},
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "D"  , Description="My D"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(240),Y= Constraint.Constant(175)},
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "E"  , Description="My E"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(290),Y= Constraint.Constant(180)},
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "F"  , Description="My F"  ,X = Constraint.Constant(335),Y= Constraint.Constant(185)}
        };
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Text { get; internal set; }
    public string Description { get; internal set; }
    public Constraint X { get; set; }
    public Constraint Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it's not working. So I started with a fresh project using the Xamarin Mobile App template. I modified Item.cs and MockDataStore.cs and ItemsPage.xaml according to your suggestions. the .cs files needed "using Xamarin.Forms;" added to them in order to compile. No go. I then added "<Image x:Name="Image" Source="bg.png" WidthRequest="780" HeightRequest="295" BackgroundColor="Beige"/>" just before "<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>" so I could see the area where the labels should be placed. Still nothing. Compiling for Android Marshmallow.

Comment: I uploaded the project to OneDrive [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An5FXC0CDJ4nxN5uxQkLDkrPgcKzEg?e=1k9Eep)

Comment: I run your code, the problem is you bind wrong items for ItemsSource. It should be Items but not items. `<RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="cyan" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">`. By the way, you need to call `LoadItemsCommand` to prepare your data.

Comment: I copied your example exactly as it, with the lower case "i". But even after I change to upper case I in Items, still doesn't work. Also, `LoadItemsCommand` is called in the ctor in ItemsViewModel.cs.

Comment: However, this did point me in the right direction. I'm setting up a github repo for others to look to see what I did, very similar to what you said. I will post it soon.

Comment: The working solution (at least for Android) is [here](https://github.com/mjmeans/AppMC/tree/master/AppMC/AppMC). Thanks Nico!